# Run a function infinite times

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, infinite

I'm trying to make a video game engine which must run the `render` function as a loop. When this function is finished, I want to run it again, and again, and again... But when I try this :

```
function render() {
    // some code here which takes ~ 0.00015 second to run
}

while(1) { render(); }
```

The browser freeze in a few seconds. So I've tried another way :

```
function render() {
    // some code here which takes ~ 0.00015 second to run
}

setTimeout(render);
// I've tried also
setTimeout(render, 1);
```

Also :

```
function render() {
    // some code here which takes ~ 0.00015 second to run

    setTimeout(render);
    // OR
    setTimeout(render, 1);
}
```

But that runs the function only ~ 500 times at a second, I want to run it ~ 5000 times. That's possible if I look the running time (0.00015 second) but I can't find a way to do that.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Try [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), but if you *already* get 500 fps, why need more?

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski: You should repost this as answer.

Comment: @drheart someone already FGITWed that one, but to be honest, I'm quite dubious about OP's 500 fps figure ;)

Comment: A game engine needs at most 60fps.

Comment: Yes 500 fps are really too high for an engine but the code I'm running is simply drawing 3 rectangles on the screen, so if I can't render 5000 times in a second what will happen when rendering a lot of big images and animations ?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is use [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) this way:

```
function render() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

You can never get an "infinite" amount of calls, that will depend on how strong your hardware is. You can also easily calculate "delta time" (amount of time passed between two consecutive `render` calls) to make the game animation smooth for any user no matter what their hardware is.

Comment: By calculating the time needed to run the `render` function I can see that whatever I use (requestAnimationFrame, setInterval) I can't run the functions 5000 times at a time. But it should be possible, I don't understand why it doesn't work. For the `window.requestAnimationFrame` way, that set a maximum of 60 fps but doesn't permit to reduce the "delta time".

I'll try to measure the delta time of the different ways I've tested and post a report here tomorrow.

Comment: (Sorry for the late) After a few tests, the delta time is (strangely) about 2 times higher with `requestAnimationFrame` than with a simple `setTimeout` (that was not `setInterval` I've edited my question). And when I put 4000 polygons on the screen, the FPS are about 2 times higher with the `setTimeout` way.....